# How do I fix MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py

After running my `Discord.py` bot, Whenever I use the help command I get the error shown below:

```
"discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing."
```

Here is my current help command, why would it give an error?

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def help(ctx, *, member, author):
        author = ctx.message.author
    
        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.red()
        )
    
        embed.set_author(name='Help Page')
        embed.add_field(name='**[.ping]**', value='*Returns Pong!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.say]**', value='*Gives you the ability to make the bot say whatever you want!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.8ball]**', value='*Function that acts just as an 8Ball.*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.ban]**', value='*Bans Users!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.kick]**', value='*Kicks Users!*', inline=False)    
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You actually need to pass it when invoking the command, i.e `!help {member} {author}`. If  you don't want that you can simply delete the author parameter

Comment: remove the author parameter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to pass a member, but if you need to, you can mention a member along with the help command:

`!help @member`, but also does not need to be required, if you don't include a member, the member will just be the command author (you)

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def help(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
        if member == None:
            member = ctx.author

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.red()
        )
    
        embed.set_author(name='Help Page')
        embed.add_field(name='**[.ping]**', value='*Returns Pong!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.say]**', value='*Gives you the ability to make the bot say whatever you want!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.8ball]**', value='*Function that acts just as an 8Ball.*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.ban]**', value='*Bans Users!*', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='**[.kick]**', value='*Kicks Users!*', inline=False)    
    
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```